# Unexpected behavior of jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I made this animated sidebar:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="block"><a class="link" href="#link1">Menu Option 1</</div>
    <div class="block">Menu Option 2</div>
    <div class="block">Menu Option 3</div>
    <div class="block">Menu Option 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:200px; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 100;
}

.block{
    width:5%;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.link{
    text-indent: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slider {
    border:1.5px solid black;
    width:10px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
//Sidbar Animations
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
  $(this)
    .animate({
      width: "90%"
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 400
    }).css("text-indent", "0");
});
$(".block").mouseout(function() {
  $(this)
    .animate({
      width: "5%"
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 500
    }).css("text-indent", "100%");
});
```

And It kinda works, but not exactly as expected.
So If I add link inside the div, it still gets animated, but sometimes animation breaks and div collapses, and it's getting hard to actually click the link.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znxygpdw/

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Each time the mouse hovers the link, it triggers a mouseout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above it would be better to use the hover function. However you problem lies with the `mouseout` function, when you hover over the link with the block the event is fired. To fix this, use the `mouseleave` function instead.

```
//Sidbar Animations
    $(".block").mouseover(function() {
      $(this)
        .animate({
          width: "90%"
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 400
        }).css("text-indent", "0");
    });
    $(".block").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this)
        .animate({
          width: "5%"
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 500
        }).css("text-indent", "100%");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/znxygpdw/4/

Comment: nice explanation, btw you forgot to replace ```mouseout``` with ```mouseleave``` in your jsfiddle link

Answer (score 4):

In this case is better to use `hover` function:

```
//Sidbar Animations
$(".block").hover(function() {
    $(this)
    .animate({
        width: "90%"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 400
    }).css("text-indent", "0");
}, function() {
    $(this)
    .animate({
        width: "5%"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    }).css("text-indent", "100%");
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/znxygpdw/1/

Comment: Are you using a callback function to create collapse animation?

Comment: Hover take 2 functions as arguments, an alias for 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'.